# Consume Redis messages with a pool of workers

Tags: python, redis, message-queue, publish-subscribe, python-multiprocessing

I have a Redis list where a publisher pushes some messages (JSON serialized).

On the other side the subscriber can fetch each JSON blob and do something. The simplest way is to do this serially. But I'd like to make it a little bit faster; I'd like to maintain a pool of worker processes (multiple consumers) and whenever a new message arrive check if there is a "free" process from the pool that can start processing
I'm looking for Pool-based version of the following

```
while not False:
    _, new_user = conn.blpop('queue:users')
    if not new_user:
        continue
    try:
        process_new_user(new_user, conn)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
    else:
        pass
```

However I can't translate this into code that uses pythons multiprocessing.Pool class. The documentation doesn't help either

Answer (score 0):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


pool = Pool()

while 1:
    _, new_user = conn.blpop('queue:users')

    if not new_user:
        continue

    pool.apply_async(process_new_user, args=(new_user, conn))
```

If you want to handle exceptions you need to collect the `AsyncResult` objects returned by `pool.apply_async` and check their status.

If you can use Python 3, [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/concurrent.futures.html?highlight=concurrent.futures#module-concurrent.futures) Pools allow to handle results in asynchronous callbacks making easier to check the jobs exit status.